# How to delete an already preceding migration in postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-migration

I have a basic migration file that does the following

```
exports.shorthands = undefined;

exports.up = pgm => {
    pgm.sql(`
        CREATE TABLE comments (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            updated_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            contents VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL
            );
        `);
};

exports.down = pgm => {
    pgm.sql(`
        DROP TABLE comments; 
    `);
};
```

When I do `DATABASE_url=postgres://hrushi@localhost:5432/socialnetwork npm run migrate up` I get error

```
> ig@1.0.0 migrate
> node-pg-migrate up

Error: Not run migration 1679060101968_table-comments is preceding already run migration 1678898668879_table-comments
    at checkOrder (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/node-pg-migrate/dist/runner.js:110:19)
    at exports.default (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/node-pg-migrate/dist/runner.js:156:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

This is most likely because of some old attempt of the same file.

Things I have tried:

1. Delete the table (I cannot delete the database as it has other tables)
2. Deleted the folder containing the migration files and written it from scratch but still error persists
3. Kill any process that is being shown in pgadmin
4. Logged into psql, and \d shows no table (any created migration creates a new table right)
5. Did npm knex

> ```
> npx knex migrate:latest
> No configuration file found and no commandline connection parameters passed
> Error: No configuration file found and no commandline connection parameters passed
>     at checkConfigurationOptions (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/knex/bin/utils/cli-config-utils.js:104:11)
>     at initKnex (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:57:5)
>     at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:247:32)
>     at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:482:17)
>     at /Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1283:65
>     at Command._chainOrCall (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1177:12)
>     at Command._parseCommand (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1283:27)
>     at /Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1081:27
>     at Command._chainOrCall (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1177:12)
>     at Command._dispatchSubcommand (/Users/hrushi/Desktop/ig/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1077:23)
> ```

How to solve this issue, would be grateful for any help

Comment: Before running the migrations, the runner checks a given table for which migrations have been run previously which you will also need to modify. If you have set a non-default `migrationsTable`, you will need to inspect this table to find the migrations that are conflicting with the one you want to run.  I believe the default table is `pgmigrations` for node-pg-migrate if you haven't provided a table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! I had a `pgmigrations` table in my `user` database which had this particular entry that was likely causing the issue. When I deleted the table and tried the migration again it worked! Not sure why it was there, maybe I added the wrong db name when I ran the migration initially.